# Why do I get an error for not having a return statement even though I have one in my for loop?

Tags: java, return

I am writing a method that is part of a Queue class for a college assignment. It is supposed to search a linked list for an object and if it is found return the index of the object, and if it isn't then it returns -1. When I don't have the "return -1;" statement in my code below I get an error saying that I don't have a return statement when I clearly have one above in the for loop. What is the issue here?

```
    public int find(Object item) {

    Node current = head;


    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        if(current.data.equals(item)) {
            return index;
        }
        else {
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    return -1;

}
```

Comment: The issue is that your method needs to specify what it should return if the other return statement is never executed. Otherwise, if the item you specify is not found in your linked list, what would the return value of the method be?

Comment: And you can remove the `else`.

Comment: Because the loop can end without executing the return statement inside it.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear where size is defined, but let's say that `index < size` is never true, then your return statement is never seen

Therefore, the method scope needs a final return statement for all possible code paths

Answer (score 2):

Because during compile time compiler doesn't know the value of the variables. So compiler has no way to evaluate the conditions and check if a condition is true or false. Therefore eliminating the "return -1" statement giving the error. Hope this clears your confusion.